# PHP lost SESSION vars after header()

Tags: php, session, variables, header

I keep losing the SESSION vars after redirecting with header().
I tried all the solutions that I found in similar questions like session_start() at the top of each page and exit() after header() but it doesnt work. Everytime I receive in the succlog.php page "id not set". The redirection to succlog.php works perfect.
Can you please help me?
here are the codes:

log in page:

```
session_name("session1");
session_start();
     ..........
$qry = "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `usr` = '$username' AND `pass` = '" . md5($password) . "'";
$result = mysql_query($qry);

//Check whether the query was successful or not
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['usr'] = $username;
        session_write_close(); 
        header("location: succlog.php"); //Redirect
        exit();
    }
}
```

succlog.php:

```
   session_name("session1");
   session_start(); 
    ...........
   <?php 
  if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
    echo "id".$_SESSION['id'];
  }
  else{
    echo "id not set";
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: session_name should be after session_start()

Comment: Remove the line  `session_write_close();` and check.

Comment: session_start() must be the first line of every php page

Comment: No @DevZer0 and @chirag ode its not true.
`The session name is reset to the default value stored in session.name at request startup time. Thus, you need to call session_name() for every request (and before session_start() or session_register() are called). ` Read http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php

Comment: thank you but none of these suggestions worked :(

Comment: try use ob_start() at start of the page. but if you use ob_start() the loding time of your page will slightly increase.

Comment: Ricky at every page I will use ob_start() or just at the login? before session start or after?

Comment: It's great that you found your solution! You should write it up as an answer below, in case the link doesn't work in the future.

Answer (score 0):

According to the asker:

> Ok I found it! it was a bug from iPage. Here is the solution :) http://www.ipage.com/knowledgebase/read_article.bml?kbid=600